# How to format JSON ouput in <Pre> block

Tags: reactjs, jsx

How to render a JSON into a block section

Example:

```
let in = { a:100,b:200}


render(){
     return(
           <pre>
            ......code?
          </pre>
      )

}
```

I have tried with template literals but did not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **[JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)**.

Working Code:

```js
let Data = {a:100, b:200};

const App = () => (
  <pre>
      {JSON.stringify(Data)}
  </pre>
)

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id='app' />
```

Answer (score 3):

Just stringify JSON you want to show

```
let in = { a:100,b:200}


render(){
  return(
     <pre>
       {JSON.stringify(in, '', 4)}
     </pre>
  );
}
```

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

With [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

Keep in mind that functions will be ignored.

```js
let code = { a: 100, b: 200, c: function(){} };

const App = () => (
  <code>
    {JSON.stringify(code)}
  </code>
);

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
 <div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Why do you wrap a string into an interpolation?